# Git push, what should be the branch name?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-push

EDIT : Thank you all for help, My intention for this question was basically on the lines of [Shared repository model](https://gist.github.com/seshness/3943237)

A newbie to github.

I have cloned a branch from github using the command

```
git clone -b amigo --single-branch <git_path.git> localFolderName
```

I then *cd* to localFolderName and do a

```
git pull
```

Next, I create a local branch

```
git branch beautiful_branch
```

followed by

```
git checkout beautiful_branch
```

I then make all the changes to the code, do a

```
git add <fileName> <fileName2>
```

and then do a commit

```
git commit -m "My first commit"
```

Now the Question is, I want to commit my `beautiful_branch` to `amigo` and do a pull request. I am not sure what should be my push command ?

if I do

```
git branch -a
```

It shows me

```
*beautiful_branch
amigo
remotes/origin/amigo
```

I have tried

```
git push -u amigo beautiful_branch
```

and

```
git push -u origin/amigo beautiful_branch
```

but I get fatal error

fatal: 'amigo' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

**It would help if you could let me know what should be the git command to push to the amigo branch.??**

EDIT:

I am following all the above steps so that I can do a pull request from github and ask for a review to my code before it is being merged.

Comment: Newbie to github or git?

Comment: To create a new branch and checkout on it in one command, just type git checkout -b new_branch_name 

This is my advice for you to not loose time with git commands...^^

Comment: @DamienVauchel (psst: *loose = less tight, lose = act of being lost)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks for english lessons ahah I think I might said "not to loose" then?

Comment: Why did you create a new branch if you didn't actually want it? If you actually want (and *need*) to work with multiple branches you should be merging or rebasing them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, what I understood so far is that once you create a new branch, you can do a pull request on github and ask for a review before merging it to main branch. Let me know if my understanding is not correct? Thank you.

Comment: ahha..a downvote, i wonder where I failed? :(

Comment: But you're not describing making a PR. If you're planning on making it from amigo, what's the point of beautiful_branch? If you're planning on making it *to* amigo, you're asking completely the wrong question. Start by reading e.g. https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/ rather than asking vague questions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok, understood. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to merge amigo and beautiful Branch. For that

1. Checkout out to Amigo

   ```
   git checkout amigo
   ```
2. Merge amigo and beautiful-branch

   ```
   git merge beautiful_branch
   ```

Now you have beautiful_branch changes in amigo. To push these to your origin, do

```
    git push origin amigo
```

EDIT:

Since you need to merge beautiful branch with amigo by somebody's review, you have to push from your local beautiful_branch to  your origin beautiful branch and then raise a pull request from beautiful branch to amigo branch.

1. Commit your changes to beautiful_branch
2. push your commits to your origin beautiful_branch

   `git push origin beautiful_branch`
3. Now you can goto github, choose your branch (*beautiful_branch*) by default its selected as master.
4. next to that you will find **New pull request**, in the next page choose your base branch to merge which is *amigo*.
5. Give the description for your changes in the branch raise a pull request.

That's it. whoever has the privileges to merge, will merge it to amigo after review

Comment: Ok, But i wanted to do a pull request via the beautiful_branch so that I could request a review on the code before it is merged to amigo branch.

Comment: Can you tell what exactly you want? Do you want a pull request from beautiful branch ? so that you want a review and finally merge it to amigo?

Comment: I am sorry if I have confused, I am learning the terminology of git. So if you see my question, I have pointed out all the steps that I have taken. So "beautiful_branch" is the branch that I have in my local computer, which I want to push to "amigo" and from github website, do a pull request and ask for review. I hope I am clear. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `git push origin beautiful_branch` is what I was looking for. So what I understand is, `origin` is your remote branch. You push your local branch `beautiful_branch` to remote and then via github do a pull request as explained by @arun gowdru. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
git push origin amigo
```

This will push your amigo branch to your origin remote repository.

Comment: Not sure If I understood, but what i have is a local branch "beautiful_branch" which I want to push to "amigo" and also once I push, I want to do a pull request from github and ask for a review before it is being merged.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in `beautiful_branch` branch then try push:

```
$ git checkout beautiful_branch  # 'beautiful_branch' is current branch
$ git push origin HEAD:amigo     # push for 'beautiful_branch' to remote 'amigo'
```

It will push your local branch `beautiful_branch` changes to remote `amigo` branch.

**N.B.** `HEAD:amigo` means push from local `HEAD` to remote `amigo`. Also, `HEAD` indicates the current local branch.

Comment: will it push the "beautiful_branch" to "amigo", as I don't see the reference of "beautiful_branch" in the command. I ask this because I will be pushing to my work code and being a newbie, I don't know how to revert changes so I want to be a little careful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it will push the `beautiful_branch` branch to remote `amigo` branch. Updated answer.